# Does Craft / Twig support regex groups?

Tags: replace, regex

I see Craft [does support regex in replace search.](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#replace) But there is no info on using regex groups, ie `string | replace('/this is a (string)/', 'This is another $1')`.

Is this feature implemented? If so - how?

Comment: Why can't I use the word boundaries?
/bWord/b is also finding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

```twig
{{ 'this is a string'|replace('/this is a (string)/', 'This is another $1') }}
```

will output

```
This is another string
```

When you pass something that looks like a regex into the `|replace` filter,  [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is called behind the scenes, so `|replace` can do anything `preg_replace()` can do.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I must somehow have had some typo in my code, as Craft threw an error on $1 when I tried initially.